# Rust function exists but is inaccessible

Tags: rust

My Rust project structure inside `src` folder:

```
|main.rs
|routes folder: 
   |-mod.rs
   |-route_func.rs
|blockchain folder:
   |simple_func.rs
```

I got this error message: `function exists but is inaccessible`

How can I use the simple_func.rs functions inside the route_func.rs ?

It seems I need to construct a module tree...

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing the actual code. Perhaps you forgot to declare a module public or something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the new module in your `main.rs` file:

```rust
pub mod blockchain;
```

Declare your new module content inside the `blockchain/mod.rs`:

```rust
pub mod simple_func;
```

Declare the target function inside `simple_func.rs`

```rust
pub async fn target_func() -> {}
```

Import the target_func in the `route_func.rs`:

```rust
use crate::blockchain::simple_func::*;
```

Remember to add `pub` in all declarations and functions!