# Holding struct from different file as a member

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have 3 structs in 3 different files, file tree:

```
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── log_recorder
│   │   ├── log_listener.rs
│   │   ├── log_writer.rs
│   │   └── mod.rs
│   ├── main.rs
│   └── utils.rs
└── target
```

One struct holds the other two.

The `log_recorder` is implemented in the `mod.rs`:

```
pub mod log_listener;
pub mod log_writer;

struct log_recorder {
    writer: log_writer,
    listener: log_listener,
    num_of_recorder_threads: u8,
    run: bool,
}

impl log_recorder {
    fn recording_loop(&self) {
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

The `log_listener` is implemented in its own file and located in the `log_recorder` dir:

```
pub struct log_listener {
    redis_client: i8,
    run: bool,
}

impl log_listener {
    fn listening_loop(&self) {
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

The `log_writer` is implemented in its own file and located in the `log_recorder` dir:

```
pub struct log_writer {
    fd: i8,
}

impl log_writer {
    fn write(&self) {
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

I keep getting errors:

```
error[E0573]: expected type, found module `log_writer`
 --> src/log_recorder/mod.rs:6:13
  |
6 |     writer: log_writer,
  |             ^^^^^^^^^^ not a type
  |
help: consider importing this struct instead
  |


error[E0573]: expected type, found module `log_listener`
 --> src/log_recorder/mod.rs:7:15
  |
7 |     listener: log_listener,
  |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^ not a type
  |
help: consider importing this struct instead
  |
```

I saw this [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48071513/how-to-use-one-module-from-another-module-in-a-rust-cargo-project), [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75412389/rust-function-exists-but-is-inaccessible), but it didn't solve it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `mod.rs`, `log_writer` and `log_listener` refer to the modules, not the types. You need to fully qualify them: `log_writer::log_writer` and `log_listener::log_listener`.

However, you should always follow Rust style conventions, [which include using `PascalCase` naming for types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/style-guide/advice.html#names). By that convention, your structs should be named `LogRecorder`, `LogListener` and `LogWriter` (while the modules stay with the same name as currently). Then, you can import them at the top of `mod.rs`:

```rust
use log_writer::LogWriter;
use log_listener::LogListener;
```

And use the unqualified names `LogWriter` and `LogListener` instead of the fully-qualified `log_writer::LogWriter` and `log_listener::LogListener`.